# Кто-нибудь знает быстрые русские сервера для спидтеста?

Tags: сервер, ftp

Нужна возможность скачать файлы разных размеров, скажем, 1 мб, 10 мб, 100 мб и загрузить с последующим автоматическим удалением по окончании. Скачивать по прямой ссылке.
Что-то вроде такого места https://testdebit.info/  , но оно далеко по расположению и медленное

Comment: Какого "такого места"? Существуют различные скрипты, тестирующие up/down для зеркал и сортирующие по скорости, например

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос